# Need help in making android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-edittext, android-widget

I am learning android development. But I am stucked that ui element don't show in my app's second activity. When loaded.

I am using AIDE in my android mobile.

Please take a look at the codes I used up.

**Main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MSQ CORP" 
        />

    <DigitalClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/newpage"
        android:text="New Page"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.msqcorp;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.View. *;
import android.widget.Button.*;
import android.content.Intent. *;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newpage);
        a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.msqcorp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="secondActivity"
            android:label="New Page"
    />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registeration Form" 
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
    />

    <TextView 
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full Name : "
        android:id="@+id/text2"
    />

    <EditText
        android:textSize="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your Full Name" 
        android:id="@+id/text3"
    />


</LinearLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
package com.mycompany.msqcorp;
import android.system.*;
import android.app. *;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.View. *;
import android.content. *;
import android.test.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class secondActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);


    }

}
```

When I run the app, it shows the first screen properly with buttons and text view

But when loaded next page on button press it shows blank screen. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a . (dot) in front of activity declaration in manifest for second activity.

```
 <activity
            android:name="secondActivity"
            android:label="New Page"
    />
```

it should be

```
<activity
            android:name=".secondActivity"
            android:label="New Page"
    />
```

**Edit:**
For you second activity try to change onCreate method to

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }
```

Check if it helps

Comment: I thought it would crash if the activity you input in android name is not correct or does not exist.

Comment: Yes it should crash but in case of @Shoaib Quraishi according to his code its showing blank screen. May be its crashing but some how he could not produce it or device is not producing it. By looking code the only reason application is not behaving properly is the . dot he is missing. else everything is correct.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya my second activity screen is still blank. I am using AIDE on my android phone, to make a app. Is There any possible conditions which preventing the app to show the UI Elements on screen?? Please help

Answer (score 0):

use "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" method instead of "public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState)"

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name="secondActivity"
            android:label="New Page"
    />
```

change this code and try

```
  <activity
            android:name=".secondActivity"
            android:label="New Page"
    />
```

Comment: Sir @Abhinav Singh Maurya I tried even applying dots but it still showing blank screen